# Azure Blob Storage's ListBlobsSegmentedAsync method doesn't return metadata if metadata value is empty

Tags: c#, azure

Calling ListBlobsSegmentedAsync method of Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob's (11.1.2) CloudBlobContainer attaches the blob **metadata** if BlobListingDetails.Metadata parameter (3rd) is set. However if blob metadata's **value** is empty, the metadata is not returned at all.

In turn, the metadata with empty value is displayed in the Storage Explorer.

```
BlobResultSegment blobList = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(blobPath, true, BlobListingDetails.Metadata, null, continuationToken, null, null);
                
foreach (CloudBlockBlob blobItem in blobList.Results)
{
  // trying to access blobItem's metadata
}
```

**Edit:** It seems it's not possible to create metadata with empty value through Azure Storage Blob's API (throws ArgumentException). However with Storage Emulator it's possible.
[image]

I need to upload blobs containing metadata with empty ("" or null) value, is it possible somehow?

**Edit 2:** The feature is working with `Azure.Storage.Blobs v.12.8.3`. I'm using `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob v11.1.2`. *So the question applies to this library!*

Comment: Basically, it is not allowed to set metadata with an empty value, but you can set value with 'null', but it is still a string value

Comment: @StanleyGong Is there any documentation that value can't be empty? Storage Emulator is able to set metadata with (seemingly) empty value.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, we can generate metadata with an empty value by Storage Emulator. But   it is not allowed using SDK or REST API, if you use SDK , it will throw an error: `value can't be a an empty string`  and if you use REST API leave header `x-ms-meta-name` empty , the value will be `null` finally

Comment: It's working with version 12 (Azure.Storage.Blobs v12.8.3)! I'm using v.11.

@StanleyGong What version are you using?

Comment: Wow, glad to know your issue has been solved.  I am also tested by v.11 as you shared your code with this version. I'll summarize your solution as an answer below, pls accept it to close this question and it will also help others I think :)

Comment: @StanleyGong The problem is not really solved, since v.12 is a totally different library (different namespace, so I think the versioning is misleading...), so I either have to use both libraries, which is not nice, or I have to migrate fully to v.12 which means rewriting the whole codebase using v.11. It should be **proven** that using v.11 with empty values in **impossible**. We can accept that through SDK it's impossible, but I haven't checked through REST API. If you confirm and update your answer that it can't be done with REST API as well I'll accept it.

Comment: Sure, I have updated my answer that using REST API to add a metadata with empty value, pls have a check :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Azure.Storage.Blobs v12.8.3` works for the scenario that adding/retrieving metadata with an empty value.

**UPDATE**

This is the step that I tried to add metadata with empty value by [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-metadata):

[image]

**Result**:

Though I leave metadata value as empty,to check its result on Azure Portal, it is set as `null` :

[image]

I also tried to remove all characters in textbox, but it is not allowed to update:
[image]